# Fixed-width middle div and two elastic-width divs either side of it

Tags: css, html, layout, elasticlayout

I am trying to create an arrangement whereby there are three divs within a div that fills up 100%-width of a page. The middle div will have a fixed width and the two outer divs will take up 50% each of the remaining space. Is this achievable using CSS?

I have set up a fiddle, that doesn't work, http://jsfiddle.net/6y5hn/ with my attempt at achieving this, with the following code:

```
<div id="outerbox">
    <div id="leftbox">(elastic width) This should occupy all the space in the grey box to the left of the red box</div>
    <div id="centerbox">(fixed-size) should be in the center of the grey box</div>
    <div id="rightbox">(elastic width) This should occupy all the space in the grey box to the right of the red box</div>
</div>
```

With the CSS:

```
#outerbox {
    background-color:gray;
    margin-top:50px;
    width:100%;
    height:200px;
}

#centerbox {
    background-color:red;
    margin-left:auto;
    margin-right:auto;
    float:left;
    height:100px;
    width:300px;
}

#leftbox {
    background-color:yellow;
    height:300px;
    float:left;
}

#rightbox {
    background-color:pink;
    height:300px;
    float:left;
}
```

James

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if this is achievable using only CSS, but here's a handy snippet of JavaScript code that can help you manage fixed and percent-based page widths more effectively:

```
function resize() {
    // the more standards compliant browsers (mozilla/netscape/opera/IE7) use window.innerWidth and window.innerHeight

if (typeof window.innerWidth != 'undefined') {
    viewportwidth = window.innerWidth,
    viewportheight = window.innerHeight
}

// IE6 in standards compliant mode (i.e. with a valid doctype as the first line in the document)

else if (typeof document.documentElement != 'undefined' && typeof document.documentElement.clientWidth != 'undefined' && document.documentElement.clientWidth != 0) {
    viewportwidth = document.documentElement.clientWidth,
    viewportheight = document.documentElement.clientHeight
}

// older versions of IE

else {
    viewportwidth = document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].clientWidth,
    viewportheight = document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].clientHeight
}

}
```

You can then call the `resize()` function on page load, as well as on page resize. So something like:

`<body onload="resize()">`

From here, because you have a calculated width of the page, you can resize your individual `div`s accordingly:

```
document.getElementById("leftbox").style.width = (viewportwidth - 300)/2 + "px";
document.getElementById("rightbox").style.width = (viewportwidth - 300)/2 + "px";
document.getElementById("centerbox").style.width = 300 + "px";
```

The `centerbox` maintains a fixed with of 300 pixels, while `leftbox` and `rightbox` have widths equal to the width of the screen minus 300 pixels, divided by two.

Answer (score 1):

add `width:calc(50% - 150px);` to `#leftbox` and `#rightbox` (150px = half of the centerbox width)

http://jsfiddle.net/6y5hn/2/

browser support: http://caniuse.com/calc

Comment: what browsers support that? god that is such a wonderful construction, thanks!!

Answer (score 1):

Just use float with the a fixed width

```
#fixed{float:left;width:360px;background-color:green;height:100%;color:yellow;}

#elastic{background-color:#ddd;height:100%;color:grey;}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/am46bm43/