# One fixed width div and two variable

Tags: html, css

I am trying to get three divs lined up beside each other. the left div has a fixed width, the middle has a percent width, and the third should take up the remaining space. Here is the code I have come up with:

HTML:

```
<div id="left">Left</div>
<div id="middle">Middle</div>
<div id="right">Right</div>
```

CSS:

```
#left {
    float:left;
    width:200px;
    height:100px;
    background-color:#A00;
    opacity:0.3;
}
#middle {
    float:left;
    width:55%;
    height:100px;
    background-color:#0A0;
    opacity:0.3;
}
#right {
    background-color:#CCC;
    height:40px;
}
```

I have made the two left divs transparent so you can see that the background of the right div extends all the way to the left of the page. How can I fix this? I have tried floating the right div however it doesn't fill the rest of the space. [here](http://jsfiddle.net/eMbV7/1/) is a fiddle I used.

Comment: http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/

Comment: possible duplicate of [Fixed-width middle div and two elastic-width divs either side of it](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19937321/fixed-width-middle-div-and-two-elastic-width-divs-either-side-of-it)

Comment: @enapupe I tried that. It seems to change the size of the fixed div too: http://jsfiddle.net/eMbV7/10/

Comment: McAngus, all three of these answers seem to solve your problem. If you ended up using one of them, I'd suggest marking it as the accepted answer to help people viewing in the future find it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

S.B. provided a great answer, but here's an alternative method just for fun. You could have everything `display:block;` like normal, then `float:left;`, and use `calc()` to get the width of the final column. It would just be `100%` - `55%` - `200px`, or compressed, `45% - 200px`.

Benefit to this is that you don't need to have the `#container`. Potential issue is browser support, mostly mobile browsers. See: http://caniuse.com/calc

#### HTML:

```
<div id="left">Left</div>
<div id="middle">Middle</div>
<div id="right">Right</div>
```

#### CSS:

```
#container {
    width: 100%;
}
#left {
    float:left;
    width:200px;
    height:100px;
    background-color:#A00;
    opacity:0.3;
}
#middle {
    float:left;
    width:55%;
    height:100px;
    background-color:#0A0;
    opacity:0.3;
}
#right {
    float:left;
    background-color:#CCC;
    height:100px;
    width:calc(45% - 200px);
}
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/eMbV7/9/

Comment: I'm fairly new to CSS. Is this good practice? I only ask this because I can't say I've ever seen calc before.

Comment: It's good practice in that it's official CSS3 in the CSS3 spec ... browser support can be tricky though: http://caniuse.com/calc

Answer (score 2):

The easiest solution would be to just wrap the 3 `div` Elements in a container, like this:

```
<div id="container">
    <div id="left">Left</div>
    <div id="middle">Middle</div>
    <div id="right">Right</div>
</div>
```

And then just make the child elements `display: table-cell` and the parent `display: table` and `width: 100%`.

```
#left, #middle, #right {
    display: table-cell;
}
#container {
    display: table;
    width: 100%;
}
```

I order to force the `#left` Element to keep it's width even when there is very little space, I'd suggest to also add `min-width: 200px` to it's CSS.

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/eMbV7/11/

Comment: This changes the width of the cell that is meant to be fixed.

Comment: Well, only when you get below a certain width. In that case, add `min-width: 200px` to `#left`. :) Like so: http://jsfiddle.net/eMbV7/11/

Comment: Updated the answer to reflect that change.

Answer (score 1):

Use this code, I have wrapped all div in a container div.

```
<div class="container">
    <div id="left">Left</div>
    <div id="middle">Middle</div>
    <div id="right">Right</div>
</div>
```

& css

```
.container{
    display:block;
    padding:0 0 0 200px;
}

#left {
    float:left;
    width:200px;
    height:100px;
    background-color:#A00;
    opacity:0.3;
    margin:0 0 0 -200px;
}
#middle {
    float:left;
    width:55%;
    height:100px;
    background-color:#0A0;
    opacity:0.3;
}
#right {
    float : right;
    width: 45%;
    background-color:#CCC;
    height:40px;
}
```

Here is jsFiddle link [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/eMbV7/8/)

Comment: This doesn't fix his problem of having the third div extend across the middle div...

Comment: That looks great in the way it works, but I don't understand exactly *why* it's working. Why does the `padding` not push the `#left` over?

Comment: cause parent container has padding left & #left has same amout of -ve margin-left

Comment: That's clever! +1 to you